# Prestashop multi store not displaying price including tax

Tags: php, e-commerce, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

After much trial and error I've set up multi store, with one store at http://margaretdabbs.nl/ and one store at http://shop.aspadirect.nl/.

It works pretty much as it should, except that it shows the product prices without VAT.

In customer groups, I've set every group so that they should see the price including tax, for every store. However, the prices are still displayed without tax. What can I do to resolve this?

Is there a way to hardcode prices including tax in templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea what the problem was, but what ended up working was re-setting the price for each product individually, per store.